# Select a UITextField by tag

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` inside my `UITableViewCell` knowing that my `UITableView` contains 3 rows, and I'm differentiating each `UITextField` putting a new tag like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
...
    cell.myTextField.tag = indexPath.row;
...
}
```

It is known also that there is a function called 'getByTag', which is so called must catch the existing text in the UITextField whose tag equals 2, so I tried this:

```
-(void)getByTag{

NSLog(@"Text is -> %@",cell.myTextField.tag[2].text);

}
```

The code `myTextField.tag[2]` did not work as I expected because I believe this means selecting not work very well and give me a compiler error. Could someone give me some help on how I can get around this error compilation and make my program select the existing text in my UITextField whose tag is equal to 2?

Comment: You should use delegate methods for UItextfields.

Comment: how you are calling getByTag function , on touch of cell or on  click of some button?

Comment: @pawan I call clicking on button!, I try this http://pastebin.com/gxGyMLwT, but Im receiving null in slog :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
-(void)getByTag:(NSInteger)myTag {
    NSMutableArray *cells = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSInteger j = 0; j < [self.tableView numberOfSections]; ++j)
    {
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:j]; ++i)
        {
            [cells addObject:[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:j]]];
        }
    }

    for (MyCustomTableViewCell *cell in cells)
    {
        if (cell.myTextView.tag == tag) {
            NSLog(@"Text is -> %@", cell.myTextField.text);
        }
    }
}
```

And call it by:

```
[self getByTag:2];
```